# Android samsung s6 SM-G920F marshmallow unable to delete data when i uninstall the application

Tags: android, sqlite

i am working with sqlight data base my application work fine on below **6.0 version** but i when in installed APK file on **samsung s6 SM-G920F model 6.01**
i am **unable to delete sqlight data** when in i **uninstalled application** .
**all the data remains when i again installed the same apk file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="srecorder">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".GPSApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"

        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateUnchanged"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <activity
            android:name=".TermsAndConditions"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_termsandconditions"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <!--<activity-->
            <!--android:name=".ChooseApplication"-->
            <!--android:label="@string/title_activity_choose_application"-->
            <!--android:screenOrientation="portrait"-->
            <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />-->
        <!--<activity-->
            <!--android:name=".Outlet"-->
            <!--android:label="@string/title_activity_outlet"-->
            <!--android:screenOrientation="portrait" />-->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_outlet"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />



        <activity
            android:name=".Header"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LogoHeader"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PendingApproval"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />






    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your manifest file

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath i have edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

```
 <application
    android:name=".GPSApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
```

Read more here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#allowbackup

Comment: Good answers very helpful

Answer (score 0):

In case of  `android:allowBackup="true"` in your manifest
you can Do it by increasing database version in your database handler
By using that you can handle both things

> 1. when you don't want to loose data don't need to increase database version with `android:allowBackup="true"`
> 2. when you want to have backup then need to increase database version and `android:allowBackup="true"`